# Test for the convergence of the series $1/5 + 2!/5^2 + 3!/5^3+\ldots $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

The series is
$1/5 + 2!/5^2 + 3!/5^3+\ldots $

It's $n$th term will be $n!/5^n $

The problem I'm facing that I'm getting infinity using D'Alembert's ratio test.

Comment: Since you got infinity (which is greater than $1$) the series is divergent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is divergent. Notice that $n!$ grows faster than any exponential function.

Notice that computing a factorial requires you to multiply the previous answer by the next integer. But exponentiation requires you to always multiply the previous answer by the same integer. Hence at a certain point you will be multiplying the result of the factorial function by integers bigger than the base of the exponential function, always. So your sum will be summing up bigger and bigger terms, so it is divergent.

Comment: @DeepakSingh What can you conclude from the ratio test if you get infinity?

Comment: @gary in ratio test (Un+1/Un) we have criteria for limit of ratio if < 1 or >1 to be cgt or dgt respectively. I'm getting infinity, & don't know in case of infinity can we use this test......